# Dependency injected DbContext in a SignalR hub does not pull latest data

Tags: kendo-ui, signalr, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core MVC site, I have a SignalR hub that has my `DbContext` injected into the constructor.  The hub pulls data from the database and send it to a kendo ui grid for the user to view.  This data is filtered in that hub on which group is selected (stored in the database).

The group selection is done outside the context of the hub.  When I change the users selected group the page reloads to update various UI elements.  When the signalr hub is then called, the selected group is still set as what it was prior to the change.  After digging for a bit I came across [this issue on the signalr github](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/106).  What I understand is because the hub is transient, the `DbContext` is as well and since the hub is long running the `DbContext` is never updated.

Is there a simple way around this while still dependency injecting the `DbContext` or do I need to create and dispose a new context for every call?  If so what is the best way to go about doing that and still pass the connection string from the `appsettings.json`?

**EDIT**

I am currently using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server` and not the new `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` library.

Comment: In a modern `signalr core` scoped services and in particular `DbContext` can be used like in `asp.net core` controllers. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59485594/4242590)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I could get around this issue with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server` was to add a `DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>` singleton to the the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` and then call that in a `using(...)` in the hub.  While I feel this is a dirty way around the issue, I also believe it is the only way around the issue.  Microsoft recently deprecated [SignalR-Server](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server) and are moving to a new code base at [SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/signalr).  Hopefully this issue will be addressed in their new version.

**Startup.cs**

```
DbContextOptionsBuilder<PortalDbContext> builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PortalDbContext>();
builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
services.AddSingleton(builder.Options);
```

**Hub Classes**

```
using (PortalDbContext dbContext = new PortalDbContext(_dbContextOptions))
{
    ...
}
```